# Getting text input from <form> to use in JS function to display on page

Tags: javascript, html, css, document.write

So I am trying to get the user to input two numbers, then click a button to run a JS function and display the result on the page. However, when I run the code, it spits back

```
NaN
```

How do I solve this problem? Is there a way I can get the tip to display on the web page?

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <title> Tip Calculator by Jonah </title>
        <div id = "links">
        <script src = "functions.js"></script>
        <link type = "text/css" rel = stylesheet href = "design.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter" rel="stylesheet">

        </div>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "cool_main">
        <h1 id = "title"> Tip Calculator </h1>
        <h2 id = "developer"> Developed by Jonah Johnson </h2>
        </div>
        <p id = "main_para"><b> Enter the meal cost then a tax percentage,and hit OK!</b></p>

        <form id = "meal_cost">
        Meal Total Here :<br>
        <input type="text" id = "meal__cost" name="mealcost" /><br>
        </form>
        <form id = "tax_percent">
        Tax Here (in percent) :<br>
        <input type ="text" id = "tax_per" name="taxpercent" ><br>
        </form>
        <h4 id = "per"> % </h4>
        <button id = "getTip" onclick = "addTogether()"> OK </button>
    </body> 
</html>
```

My JS:

```
var taxValue = document.getElementById("tax_per").value;

var meal__Cost = document.getElementById("meal__cost").value;

function addTogether() {
    document.write(taxValue * meal__cost);
}
```

My CSS:

```
div {
position: relative;
left: -490px;
}



#title {
font-family: "Bitter", sans-serif;
border: 0px solid black;
width: 225px;
padding: 10px 24px;
background-color: #dbdbcb;
border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px  #888888;
position: relative;
left: 531px;
font-size: 40px;
text-align: center;

}

#developer {
font-family: "Bitter", sans-serif;
border: 0px solid black;
width: 300px;
padding : 5px 10px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #dbdbcb;
border-radius: 10px 10px;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
position: relative;
left: 510px;
}

#main_para {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 415px;
position: relative;
left: 0px;
font-family: "Bitter", sans-serif;
padding: 4px 10px;
background-color: #dbdbcb;
border-radius: 10px 10px;
}

#meal_cost {
    border: 0px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Bitter", sans-serif;
    background-color: #dbdbcb;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    position: relative;
    left: 550px;
    bottom: 200px;  
    font-size: 40px;

}

#tax_percent {
    border: 0px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Bitter", sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    background-color: #dbdbcb;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    left: 550px;
    bottom: 170px;
}

#per {
    position: relative;
    left: 856px;
    bottom: 226px;
    width: 10px;
    font-family: "Bitter", sans-serif;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. It would also be good if the displayed value was customizable in css.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function addTogether() {
var taxValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("tax_per").value);

var meal__Cost = parseInt(document.getElementById("meal__cost").value);

    document.write(taxValue * meal__Cost);
}
```

```html
<div id = "cool_main">
        <h1 id = "title"> Tip Calculator </h1>
        <h2 id = "developer"> Developed by Jonah Johnson </h2>
        </div>
        <p id = "main_para"><b> Enter the meal cost then a tax percentage,and hit OK!</b></p>

        <form id = "meal_cost">
        Meal Total Here :<br>
        <input type="text" id = "meal__cost" name="mealcost" /><br>
        </form>
        <form id = "tax_percent">
        Tax Here (in percent) :<br>
        <input type ="text" id = "tax_per" name="taxpercent" ><br>
        </form>
        <h4 id = "per"> % </h4>
        <button id = "getTip" onclick = "addTogether()"> OK </button>
```

You need to parse it into Integer or Float, as the data you are manipulating is string

```
var taxValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("tax_per").value);

var meal__Cost = parseInt(document.getElementById("meal__cost").value);
```

You can use parseFloat as well if you reuire

Comment: @Slasher yeah, the `.value` will give you string

Comment: and you should get the values when you are submiting. so the function add to gether on click should pull the values, parse to float or integer gepending on what you intend and add them, then display them

Comment: @Slasher its because, you have used the wrong variable name, be aware of the case `meal__Cost`. Also I have placed a working snippet

Comment: @Slasher check the snippet I have created, and please work on your logics :)

Comment: The problem is that when the user inputs the tax, they have to add a period in front of the number to have it as a tax. So how are you able to add that without getting an error?

Comment: Mate use parseFloat then.

Answer (score 1):

You wrong with variable name case and you must retrieve the value when user clicks the button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <title> Tip Calculator by Jonah </title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "cool_main">
        <h1 id = "title"> Tip Calculator </h1>
        <h2 id = "developer"> Developed by Jonah Johnson </h2>
        </div>
        <p id = "main_para"><b> Enter the meal cost then a tax percentage,and hit OK!</b></p>

        <form id = "meal_cost">
        Meal Total Here :<br>
        <input type="text" id = "meal__cost" name="mealcost" value="0" /><br>
        </form>
        <form id = "tax_percent">
        Tax Here (in percent) :<br>
        <input type ="text" id = "tax_per" name="taxpercent" value="0"><br>
        </form>
        <h4 id = "per"> % </h4>
        <button id = "getTip" onclick = "addTogether(); return false;"> OK </button>

        <div id = "links">

        </div>
        <script >

            function addTogether() {
                var taxValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tax_per").value);

                var meal__cost = parseFloat(document.getElementById("meal__cost").value);

                document.getElementById("links").innerHTML= taxValue * meal__cost;
                return false;
            }

        </script>


    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: this does not display the final tax when the css sheet is added